# adding code push to react native appcenter app

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-app-center, code-push

My react native app is working ok, but now need to add code push,

my question is where to add the

> CodePush

On the "App"

Here my code,

```
const App = () => (
  
  <Provider store={store}>
    <NavigationContainer>
      <SafeAreaProvider>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Main/>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaProvider>
    </NavigationContainer>
  </Provider>
);

// let codePushOptions = { checkFrequency: CodePush.CheckFrequency.ON_APP_START };

// App = CodePush(codePushOptions)(App);

export default App;
```

But if I uncomment

```
let codePushOptions = { checkFrequency: CodePush.CheckFrequency.ON_APP_START };

App = CodePush(codePushOptions)(App);
```

export default App;

is Crashing...

How to properly add the CodePush to my App?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont have to set the value to the App, you can directly return like below

```
let codePushOptions = { checkFrequency: CodePush.CheckFrequency.ON_APP_START };

export default CodePush(codePushOptions)(App);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare a new variable. You cant use App because App is already declared and used.

```
MyApp = codePush(App);
export default MyApp;
```